# How to return a list of tuples with limit = 10 and sort it?

Tags: python

I have a function `position_list(db, limit=10)`. (`db` is a database connection and the optional argument limit is an integer).
So I want to return a `list` of `tuples` representing the positions stored in the database (with limit = 10).
Each tuple contains `(id, timestamp, owner, title, location, company, description)`.
After that I want to sort it in  reverse order of the `timestamp` (i.e. most recent first).

I've done something like:

```
def position_list(db, limit=10):
    k = ('id', 'timestamp', 'owner', 'title', 'location', 'company', 'description')
    result = []
    for i in range(limit):
        result.append(k)
        return result

    sorted(result, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)
    return result
```

1. I don't know how to use a loop to append variables (which is 10 tuples) to a `list`.
2. I don't know how to use `db` in Database Model interface.

Comment: Which database it is?

Comment: database is DATABASE_NAME = 'comp.db'.
I'm using pycharm. In database , database table is created using sqlite3. Also sample data for testing is created

Answer (score 1):

Considering sqlite3 database, as mentioned in comment. db is the handle to database, steps will be create a cursor to db, fire the query to get the data and then take row-wise data and append to result.

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''Select 'id', 'timestamp', 'owner', 'title', 'location', 'company', 'description' from TABLE_NAME''')
row1 = cursor.fetchone()
```

Then you can extract the values using row1[0],row1[1]... OR convert the list into tuple and append it to the result.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How about the limit variable ?